# How to prove that if a simple graph has a vertex which splits it into at least $2$ connected components does not have Hamiltonian cycle?

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple graph. Let $r\in V$ be a vertex whose removal (and the removal of its edges) from $G$ will result in graph $G'$ which will have more connected components than $G$.
>   Prove that $G$ does not have Hamiltonian cycle.

Suppose that $G$ is connected and is split into at least two connected components $G_1=(V_1, E_1)$ and $G_2=(V_2, E_2)$. If $|V|=n$ and $|V_1|=p$ then for vertex $a\in V_2$ which was the neighbor of $r$ we have that $\deg(a)\le n-p-1$. For vertex $b\in V_1$ which was the neighbor of $r$ we have that $\deg(b)\le p-1$.

In order for $G$ to have Hamiltonian cycle we must have $\forall x,y \in V:\deg(x)+\deg(y) \ge n$. If we check this for $a$ and $b$:
$$
\deg(a)+\deg(b)\le p-1+n-p-1=n-2
$$
Now let's "return" the vertex $r$ to $G'$ such that it becomes $G$ again. Both $a$ and $b$ have one more edge now so:
$$
\deg(a)+\deg(b)\le p-1+n-p-1+\mathbf 2=n
$$

This still doesn't prove that $G$ doesn't have Hamiltonian cycle but I don't have any other leads.

Comment: Do you see intuitively why this must be false? A Hamiltonian cycle must link both components that appear (after removal of $r$); in particular to get from one component to the other the cycle must move through $r$. But it's a cycle, and therefore has to get back to the original component, and has to move through $r$ again. But then you visit $r$ twice.

Comment: I'd appreciate explanation why the question was downvoted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Proof*.

If removing $v\in V(G)$ splits $G$ into several parts, then removing $v$ also split any possibly contained Hamiltonian cycle $C\subseteq G$ ($G$ and $C$ are defined on the same vertex set). But a cycle cannot become disconnected by removing a single vertex, because cycles are [$2$-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)).

$\square$

---

**Intuitively**, a graph that can be split by a single vertex has a single-vertex "bottleneck" (see the upper graph in the picture below). To have a Hamiltonian cycle however, you need to have bottlenecks of size not smaller than two, because you need to go in both directions through it without using the same vertex twice.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If $r-v_1-v_2-...-v_n-r$ is a Hamiltonian cycle, then $V=\{r,v_1,...,v_n\}$ and $r\neq v_i\neq v_j$, for $i\neq j$.

Therefore no edge $v_{i}-v_{i+1}$ is an edge of $r$. Therefore, removing $r$ and its edges leaves all other vertices connected by $v_1-v_2-...-v_n$.

Comment: I didn't understand your statement "Therefore no edge $v_i−v_{i+1}$  is an edge of $r$". There's an edge $r-v_1$ and $v_n-r$. so wouldn't removing $r$ make $G$ not connected because also edges $r-v_1$ and $v_n-r$ are lost?

Comment: @Yos In a simple graph and edge is determined by the pair of vertices it joins. Since $r$ is different from $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$, by definition of Hamiltonian cycle, then the edge $v_i-v_{i+1}$ cannot be neigther the edge $r-v_1$, nor the edge $v_n-r$.

Comment: I still don't understand your proof, maybe you're implying something in your answer that I still need to figure out. Can you please elaborate on why the graph is not Hamiltonian in your proof?

Comment: @Yos There nowhere a claim of not being Hamiltonian. Hamiltonian is assumed, the vertex $r$ is removed, and everything else is the argument of why the graph remains connected after $r$ gets removed.

Comment: You suppose (by contradiction I guess?) that the graph is Hamiltonian. Then you remove $r$. But how is the resulting graph still connected if it's split into at least two connected components making the original graph not connected.

Comment: @Yos Not by contradiction. I proved the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition): *For all simple graphs, if it has a Hamiltonian cycle, then the removal of a vertex must leave it connected.* If $\text{not }Q\implies\text{not }P$, then $P\implies Q$. Applying this to the proposition I proved we get that: *For all simple graphs, if the removal of a vertex disconnects it, then there is no Hamiltonian cycle*.

Comment: For example this is a Hamiltonian graph: https://imgur.com/a/ozIbbTD as the degree of each vertex is at least $\frac{7}{2}=3$. But after removing the orange vertex the graph is not connected anymore but has 2 connected components

Comment: @Yos You think about. I already gave you all the tools you need. If it got disconnected it clearly doesn't have any Hamiltonian **cycle**.

Comment: I appreciate your help but your answer didn't help me, it gave me more questions instead of answers.